# Gitlab SSL Handshake failed server most likely require client certificate

Tags: ssl, networking, openssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate

Everything was working fine from months I was able to clone/fetch/push/pull from my Gitlab repo on my mac:

Suddenly started to get this error on mac:

When I run the command:

git fetch "repo_link" I get the following error

unable to access : SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect.

git config http.sslVerify false is already set.

Even if try to fetch/push/pull from Android studio getting the same error.

Tried clone/fetch on another mac it's working fine.

Please help.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. On mac I selected Go -> Home. Then deleted the .gitconfig file. Worked for me. You can also try to delete .ssh folder as well

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by using SSL instead of HTTPS.

I simply added another remote repo using the following command

```
git remote add org git@gitlab.com:***/***.git
```

Replace *** with your SSH path details

Then add an SSH to your GitLab account from [here](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys)

To add an SSH key you need to [generate one](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#generate-an-ssh-key-pair) or use an [existing key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#see-if-you-have-an-existing-ssh-key-pair).

Once the key has been added to your GitLab account you can try

```
git push -u org master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the sslVerify
locally at repo `git config http.sslVerify true` or globally `git config --global http.sslVerify true`